# What is the meaning of 範囲等の申請範囲 in this sentence?

Tags: translation, words, lexicalization

I'm having a hard time trying to get the meaning of 範囲等の申請範囲 in the following sentence. Context: instruction on how to fill in a form to apply for quality evaluation of wood materials.

> 青色で囲っている部分は、各材料のバリ エーション、数値の公差、範囲等の申請範囲を示す部分です。

Why the repetition of 範囲? What is the value of 等? Here is my bad attempt:

> The section circled in blue is where the write each material variation, numerical value of tolerance and *requested range of scope*.

Also, the meaning of 申請 it is not so clear to me. Could it refer to someone that requested the quality evaluation (for example a company)? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The second 範囲 isn't only for the first 範囲, but the entire phrase "各材料のバリエーション、数値の公差、範囲等".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 青色で囲っている部分は、＜｛各材料の①バリエーション、②数値の公差、③範囲、④等("etc")｝の｛申請範囲｝＞を示す部分です。

The first 範囲 refers to the tolerable *physical* range of measurement values according to the spec. I'm not sure how バリエーション, 公差 and this 範囲 differ from the professional point of view (they all seems to refer to so-called [engineering tolerance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Engineering_tolerance)). Maybe they wanted to make it very clear by saying similar words three times.

The second 範囲 in 申請範囲 refers to the extent to which this application form covers. The literal translation of 申請範囲 would be something like "application *scope*". Actually I don't see any good reason why they needed to use 範囲 here. Using the same word twice with two different meanings is certainly annoying, and I feel they could have said 申請内容 or 申請項目 instead without changing the meaning.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I think in this case a literal translation is not good, so I tried to rephrase it like this: "Indicate in the blue-circled sections each material's variation, tolerance and range that are relevant/significant for the application". Is this correct?

Comment: @Macro Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are two separate ranges/scopes (範囲) here - first one belongs to a noun 数値 and is a part of enumeration: tolerance, range, etc. - therefore the 等 right after the first occurrence of 範囲. Basically  this part  lists objects/concepts being  measured/evaluated.

The second occurrence is a separate concept： 申請範囲 - it is a set of requirements that should be fulfilled  (E.g. in a form of acceptable ranges).

So you seem to have 数値の範囲 and 申請範囲, meaning there is no repetition, at least not of a semantical type.

Comment: So 申請 in this case means "necessary", "required", "acceptable"?

Comment: @Marco Looks like "requested" to me. As if contract stipulated certain acceptable levels.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the original article in Japanese at the URL of General Building Research Corporation of Japan (GBRC). "青色で囲っている部分は、各材料のバリエーション、数値の公差、範囲等の申請範囲を示す部分です." This sentence is ambiguous even for Japanese natives. I'd like to rewrite it to be more clear. "申請範囲"　shoulde be "申請事項." Or "青色で囲っている部分は、各材料のバリエーション、数値の公差、範囲等の申請事項を示す部分です."
"等" of "範囲等" means "application scope, etc." Or the applicatio form requires (includes) "variations of materials, tolerance of size (it would be expressed in numerical value.) and the scope of services by GBRC the applicant want to have. I've not read all of the GBRC web site, but I guess there could be several services like "Express" and "Standard" or "free" and "charged." So the applicant should specify clearly the service level besides of the evaluation scope itself.Then GBRC be able to estimate the cost of the service, and so on.